# Expected steps to obtain a connected graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

We have a country containing $N$ cities with no road between any two cities (what a poor country). Each day we choose two cities such that there is no road between them and build a road between them. We choose each pair of non-connected cities with equal probability. Let $X$ be the number of days until we obtain a connected country. What is the expected value of $X$?

A friend asked me, I have no idea yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a classical result in the theory of random graphs.  The model you describe is known as the *Erdos-Renyi* random graph process $(G(n,M))_{M=0}^{n(n-1)/2}$: $G(n,0)$ is an empty graph on $n$ vertices; we obtain $G(n,M+1)$ from $G(n,M)$ by inserting a non-edge chosen uniformly at random.

In terms of marginal distribution, $G(n,M)$ is a graph on vertex set $[n]$ with $M$ edges, chosen with equal probability.

It was addressed in the paper that actually started the study of random graphs:

> P. Erdos and A. Renyi. On Random Graphs I. *Publicationes Mathematicae*, 6:290-297, 1959.

The paper can be viewed online [here](http://ftp.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1959-11.pdf).

The leading term in the expected number of edges to obtain connectivity is $\frac{1}{2}n\log n$. In fact, if
$$
M=\frac{n\log n+cn}{2},
$$
where $c=c(n)\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (no matter how slowly), then the probability that $G(n,M)$ is connected tends to 1 with $n$. On the other hand, if $c=c(n)\rightarrow-\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, then the probability of connectedness tends to 0.

Why is $\frac{n\log n}{2}$ the threshold?  It turns out that this is the threshold for the property of having minimum degree 1... and that it is very unlikely for a graph to have minimum degree 1 and not be connected.